# How to add xml nodes in a xml file at specific location using c#.net

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have a xml file with following details. Want to add another node
at 3rd position. Please share the code to help me out.

Node to Add:

```
<Field id="">
                    <Caption></Caption>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <ElementFinder>
                      <Locator>ID</Locator>
                      <Properties>username</Properties>
                    </ElementFinder>
                  </Field>
```

Original XML:

```
<ItemCollection>
              <Field id="a609022b-8604-43a9-b196-b639378eba36">
                <Caption>Enter User name</Caption>
                <Value>test</Value>
                <ActionKeyword>Input</ActionKeyword>
                <ElementFinder>
                  <Locator>ID</Locator>
                  <Properties>username</Properties>
                </ElementFinder>
              </Field>
              <Field id="5932ad89-7be3-4ddf-add1-4e3dcf2609d8">
                <Caption>Enter Password</Caption>
                <Value>Test</Value>
                <ActionKeyword>Input</ActionKeyword>
                <ElementFinder>
                  <Locator>ID</Locator>
                  <Properties>password</Properties>
                </ElementFinder>
              </Field>
              <Action id="f199a3bf-b7e3-42ae-ac02-821bdd3b076b">
                <Caption>Click on Login</Caption>
                <ActionKeyword>Click</ActionKeyword>
                <ElementFinder>
                  <Locator>LinkText</Locator>
                  <Properties>Login</Properties>
                </ElementFinder>
              </Action>                  
            </ItemCollection>
```

Comment: Please note that you are expected to show [*minimal but complete*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) codes that you have so far before asking others to provide codes to solve your problem. Provided with base code, people can see what you already knew and what particular part you need help with. And they don't have to write everything from scratch. Make it easy for those who want to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you knew how to parse XML and create a new element using LINQ-to-XML, then you should have posted the codes for the same so we can base our answer on it :

```
var raw = "string containing the XML in question";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);

var newFieldRaw = @"<Field id="""">
    <Caption></Caption>
    <Value></Value>
    <ElementFinder>
      <Locator>ID</Locator>
      <Properties>username</Properties>
    </ElementFinder>
</Field>";
var newField = XElement.Parse(newFieldRaw);
```

Then to answer the actual question, you can find the last `<Field>` element, and insert the new element using `AddAfterSelf()` :

```
var lastField = doc.Descendants("Field").Last();
lastField.AddAfterSelf(newField);
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**output :**

```
<ItemCollection>
  <Field id="a609022b-8604-43a9-b196-b639378eba36">
    <Caption>Enter User name</Caption>
    <Value>test</Value>
    <ActionKeyword>Input</ActionKeyword>
    <ElementFinder>
      <Locator>ID</Locator>
      <Properties>username</Properties>
    </ElementFinder>
  </Field>
  <Field id="5932ad89-7be3-4ddf-add1-4e3dcf2609d8">
    <Caption>Enter Password</Caption>
    <Value>Test</Value>
    <ActionKeyword>Input</ActionKeyword>
    <ElementFinder>
      <Locator>ID</Locator>
      <Properties>password</Properties>
    </ElementFinder>
  </Field>
  <Field id="">
    <Caption></Caption>
    <Value></Value>
    <ElementFinder>
      <Locator>ID</Locator>
      <Properties>username</Properties>
    </ElementFinder>
  </Field>
  <Action id="f199a3bf-b7e3-42ae-ac02-821bdd3b076b">
    <Caption>Click on Login</Caption>
    <ActionKeyword>Click</ActionKeyword>
    <ElementFinder>
      <Locator>LinkText</Locator>
      <Properties>Login</Properties>
    </ElementFinder>
  </Action>
</ItemCollection>
```